# Unable to load function install_tensorflow() in r

Tags: r, tensorflow

Hi I have encountered such problem when loading the function install_tensorflow() in r.

I don't know what to do with this error. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Below is the error message

> ERROR: Exception:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 171, in _merge_into_criterion
> crit = self.state.criteria[name]
> KeyError: 'tensorflow'

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
> yield
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 519, in read
> data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
> data = self.__fp.read(amt)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 461, in read
> n = self.readinto(b)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 505, in readinto
> n = self.fp.readinto(b)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
> return self._sock.recv_into(b)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
> return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 929, in read
> return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
> socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 189, in _main
> status = self.run(options, args)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 178, in wrapper
> return func(self, options, args)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
> reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 122, in resolve
> requirements, max_rounds=try_to_avoid_resolution_too_deep,
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 453, in resolve
> state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 318, in resolve
> name, crit = self._merge_into_criterion(r, parent=None)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 173, in _merge_into_criterion
> crit = Criterion.from_requirement(self._p, requirement, parent)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 82, in from_requirement
> if not cands:
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 124, in **bool**
> return bool(self._sequence)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in **bool**
> return any(self)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 38, in _iter_built
> candidate = func()
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 169, in _make_candidate_from_link
> name=name, version=version,
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 306, in **init**
> version=version,
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 144, in **init**
> self.dist = self._prepare()
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 226, in _prepare
> dist = self._prepare_distribution()
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 312, in _prepare_distribution
> self._ireq, parallel_builds=True,
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 457, in prepare_linked_requirement
> return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 482, in _prepare_linked_requirement
> self.download_dir, hashes,
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 234, in unpack_url
> hashes=hashes,
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 108, in get_http_url
> from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 163, in **call**
> for chunk in chunks:
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 159, in iter
> for x in it:
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/utils.py", line 88, in response_chunks
> decode_content=False,
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 576, in stream
> data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 541, in read
> raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in **exit**
> self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
> File "/Users/alexsong/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
> raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
> pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
> Error: Error installing package(s): 'tensorflow==2.4'

Comment: The error points to a internet connection problem, just try again, or make sure the connection to the internet is working properly.

Comment: I have tried several times, but it still not working. When I download other packages, they are working just fine, so I assume the connection of internet is working fine.